# Shopping cart rule to apply discount every X amount of products

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules

I want to add a shopping cart rule to my site which gives a discount every 3rd item. For example if there are 3 items for a category in the cart, provide a discount of £2, and when there are 6 items, apply discount of £4 etc. I also have to consider if a customer buys 4 or 5 they'd get the discount set on buying 3 etc. Is it possible to do this with a single rule?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, just give them the discount divided by quantity step.  If you want to give $2 discount every 3 items then you would set a Fixed Amount Discount of 0.6667 ($2 / 3) then set the Discount Qty Step to 3.  Every 3rd item will result in 0.6667 * 3 discount, or $2.

[image]

Comment: Hi Sean, I've found a problem with this. It only takes affect every 3rd addition to the cart of every single product. For example if I had 1 x 3 products from the category I've specified, I don't get the discount. I have to have 3 x 1 product (hopefully that makes sense). The offer should be any 3 items from this category?

Thank you

Comment: Do you have any other conditions besides category?

Comment: No, just that, exactly as you've shown above with my category of 8. Thanks

Comment: I'm not by my computer atm but try changing the Discount Qty Step to 1 then add an extra subselection condition to achieve the multiple of 3. I'll try it out myself when I get back home.

Comment: Hi, I've tried this but I've either done it wrong or it's just not working. How do I add the condition to be a multiple of 3? Thanks

Comment: I've tried a few different ways around this but cant seem to figure it out! :(

Comment: neither work for me when the condition is use on 3 different products of same category

Comment: @seanbreeden How can i get the Packing charge from the customer of selected products by using shopping cart pricing rule?

Comment: @seanbreeden  how to give discount for 3rd order? is possible with shopping cart pricing rule?

Answer (score 4):

I have create the issue by the following conditions for 1X3 (3 different products of same category)

[image: Rules Screenshot 1]

[image: Rules Screenshot 2]

Hope it help you all.

Comment: This solution doesn't work when you've 4 products of category 5 in your shopping cart. When you have 4 products in your shoppingcart you probably want to apply the discount for the first 3 products.

Comment: how to give discount for 3rd order? is possible with shopping cart pricing rule? @urfusion