# discount on multiple of X item

Tags: magento-1.9, php, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount

I want to give customer a discount of $5 on 3, $10 on 6, $15 on 9 and so on product of a particular category.

I tried as describe in this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/54069/shopping-cart-rule-to-apply-discount-every-x-amount-of-products) but no success.

[image]

How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution by adding following conditions.

[image]

[image]