# 5-pack or single product

Tags: magento-1.8, tierprice, product-prices

In our store we can sell 5-pack or single of our products.

We do charge more for single product compared to 5-pack. Reason is that the product is delivered to us in terms of 5-packs. So single product is basically an 5-pack / 5.

Today we use tier-prices set to 5 and above. Meaning that if a customer order a 5-pack they will get a discount for the 5 products in cart.

However, this should not apply for single products outside of the 5-pack range. So lets say I order seven units. I should pay 1 * 5-pack prices and 2 * single prices. If I order 10 units I would instead be charged the 5-pack prices for all units.

I think standard tier-price can not solve this for me and I have tried to find a good extension to handle this.

Comment: instead of tier price, you can try providing discount with shopping cart price rule. In shopping cart price rule use the feature "discount qty step" and set it to 5. that way discount will be provided to quantities of multiples of 5. Check this for full details - http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/54069/shopping-cart-rule-to-apply-discount-every-x-amount-of-products

Comment: Is it possible to get this information to be displayed at product page. Or is it a big operation to get that information at that view?

Comment: yes it is possible and its a small change. Simply call a custom CMS block on the product view page .

Answer (score 0):

You have to create 2 different product in admin.

> One is simple product with regular price
>
> Other one is a bundle product with option on same simple product with fixed qty 5 with fixed price.

Comment: Ok, that would involve some massive work in order to implement. Maybe it would be easier to rewrite tier prices somehow.